# Getting list of key values from app config with same name

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, appsettings

I have follwing in app.config file:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="Name" value="Office"/>
... 

<add key="Name" value="HotSpot"/>

...

<add key="Name" value="Home"/>
</appSettings>
```

I tried

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Name"]
```

But it only gives me one Value? How can i get list of all values? I am using c# 3.5. Is there lambda expression or something i can use to get that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only use one key per value, so this approach will not work.

There are two alternate approaches I can think of:

1. Use a single key with a delimiter, and retrieve with `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Name"].Split(new [] { "," });`.

   `<add key="Name" value="Office,Hotspot,Home" />`
2. Use a [custom section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to create a section that can contain your array of strings.

Comment: Thank you. This answered helped me. I think your quotes should be single quotes though: `new [] { "," }`.